# Debugging python code: Determine if an 'except' is waiting for an exception in some later frame

Tags: python, debugging, exception, trace

When executing a python script while having installed a trace callback via `sys.set_trace ()`, I would like to be able to distinguish between exceptions which will later be excepted in the python code explicitly and exceptions which would 'fall through' and terminate the script. Only the second type must be handled in my case (by triggering a debugger).

How can I distinguish these types ? Is going up the frame structure and looking for some frame properties an option ?

A tracer function code sample looks like this:

```
class Tracer:
  
  def __enter__ (self):
    sys.settrace (Tracer.func)
    
  def __exit__ (self, ext_type, exc_value, traceback):
    sys.settrace (None)
    
  @staticmethod
  def func (frame, event, arg):
    if event == 'exception':
      exception, value, tb = arg

      if not will_be_excepted (exception):
        notify_debugger (exception, value, tb)
        
    return Tracer.func

with Tracer () as tracer:
  # Code to trace
```

So I'm looking for some idea about how to write the `will_be_excepted ()` function in the above sample. Letting the exception pass and triggering the debugger after script termination is not an option, because I would like to break right at the frame the exception is thrown.

Comment: Just after posting this, I'm not sure anymore if the approach is correct at all. Just letting the exception pass and capturing it at the top level might be sufficient here, too, because the exception of course keeps its own traceback - and the top level frame can be used to access code and scope "post mortem". Hmm...